# JPA @Embedded annotation flagged as error In netbeans

Tags: hibernate, jpa, hibernate-annotations

### In NETBEANS

error shows at line **2** :

```java
 @Embedded    
    public SchoolDetails getSchoolDetails() {
    return schoolDetails;
     }
```

> Basic attributes can only be of the following types: Java primitive
>   types, wrapper of primitive types, String, java.math.BigInteger,
>   java.math.BigDecimal, java.util.Date, java.util.Calendar,
>   java.sql.Date, java.sql.Time, java.sql.TimeStamp, byte[], Byte[],
>   char[], Character[], enums, or any Serializable type.  embeded

note that the classes as follow

```java
package com.chapter3;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class School  {

    private int schoolId;
    private String schooleName;
    private SchoolDetails schoolDetails;

    @Embedded    
    public SchoolDetails getSchoolDetails() {
        return schoolDetails;
    }

    public void setSchoolDetails(SchoolDetails schoolDetails) {
        this.schoolDetails = schoolDetails;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public int getSchoolId() {
        return schoolId;
    }

    public void setSchoolId(int schoolId) {
        this.schoolId = schoolId;
    }

    public String getSchooleName() {
        return schooleName;
    }

    public void setSchooleName(String schooleName) {
        this.schooleName = schooleName;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.chapter3;

import javax.persistence.Embeddable;

@Embeddable
public class SchoolDetails {

    private String schoolAddress;
    private boolean isPublicSchool;
    private int studentCount;

    public boolean isIsPublicSchool() {
        return isPublicSchool;
    }

    public void setIsPublicSchool(boolean isPublicSchool) {
        this.isPublicSchool = isPublicSchool;
    }

    public String getSchoolAddress() {
        return schoolAddress;
    }

    public void setSchoolAddress(String schoolAddress) {
        this.schoolAddress = schoolAddress;
    }

    public int getStudentCount() {
        return studentCount;
    }

    public void setStudentCount(int studentCount) {
        this.studentCount = studentCount;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem Was a bug in netbeans

[netbeans issues](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=167419)

and the solution i had to implement serializable interface and the error was gone.